# Rails health check for database blocked by Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

In our Rails application we want to add a health check endpoint for things such as the DB, Sidekiq, Redis, and Cache, and this can then be consumed in a variety of ways such as an HTML view, JSON response, etc.

An example check for the database might look like:

```
  def run_db_check
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.present?
    { check_name: 'database', ok: true }
  rescue StandardError => e
    { check_name: 'database', ok: false, error_details: e.class.to_s }
  end
```

However it seems Rails or rather the MySql2 gem will throw an error way before the application gets near the health check if it detects issues with the DB.

In order to try and handle this you could add the following into the controller:

```
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError,
              ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished do |e|
    check_results = [{ check_name: 'database', ok: false, error_details: e.class.to_s }]
    render json: { ok: false, details: check_results }, status: :internal_server_error
  end
```

However this means it will block the other checks (redis, etc.)... is there a way to suppress this exception for our health controller to then allow the rest of our application code to check the other details and then manually check the db?